# R: Preventing strings (date-alike) from converting to numbers

Tags: r, excel, date

So I have these genes in R and, while their names resemble dates (eg Sept-4), I want to print them in an excel file without converting them in numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you printing these values in excel?

Comment: This is a known issue with Excel (not with R, so the `R` tag is misleading); there even exists [a paper](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-5-80) on this issue. I recommend having a read.

Comment: This question is not about R, but about Excel, Anyway, the excel tag description says: "General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User."

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response, but I need an automatic way (aka a command) in order to print the genes in an excel file. I don't want to copy and paste them. Any ideas? I heard of an "as.is" command or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you know in which cells you'll copy the dates, just format that cell to `Text`. This should leave the content as is.